# Medir cuantas letras tiene una palabra y de esas decir cual es la palabra mas larga

Tags: python, string

Me gustaría saber cómo contar los caracteres que contiene una palabra y cómo obtener la palabra con mayor cantidad de caracteres dentro de un conjunto de strings:

Ej: "hola como estas" contienen palabras con el largo: 4    4    5, de ellas
"estas" es la palabra mas larga.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
input_del_usuario = input("Que frase quires: ")
#La string mas larga...
def string_mas_larga(string, word):
    string = input_del_usuario
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "q, w, e, r, t, y, u, i, o, p, a, s, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, ñ, z, x, c, v, b, n, m":
```

Comment: `len(cadena)` te dice cuántas letras tiene la cadena que le pases. Si además usas `texto.split()`, eso dividirá la cadena `texto` en trozos, usando los espacios como separadores. El resultado será una lista en la que cada elemento será una palabra. Iterando por esa lista y haciendo `len()` de cada elemento sabes cuántas letras tiene cada palabra. Te dejo que intentes estas ideas y refines la pregunta con una duda más concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recibimos en frase el texto digitado por el usuario, lo dividimos en palabras usando `split`.

Con la función `max` podemos calcular el máximo de esta lista. El criterio para determinar si un elemento (palabra) es mayor que otro es el largo en caracteres, que se calcula con `len`.

Con el argumento `key=` le decimos como calcular el tamaño de cada palabra. Para eso definimos un `lambda` que se limita a aplicar `len(x)`, siendo `x` una palabra.

```
frase = input("Su frase:")
mas_larga = max(frase.split(), key=lambda x: len(x))
print(f"Palabra más larga es {mas_larga}, con {len(mas_larga)} letras")
```

**Demo**

```
Su frase
la mona jacinta se ha puesta una cinta
Palabra más larga es jacinta, con 7 letras
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder a mi pregunta. Me has aclarado las dudas que tenia. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

ésta sería mi solución:

```
max=0
count=0
frase = input('Inserta la frase: ')
print(frase)
palabras = frase.split()
for palabra in palabras:
    numbers.append(len(palabra))
    if len(palabra) > max:
        max=len(palabra)
        count+=1
print(numbers)
print(palabras[count-1])
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme! Me ha sido muy útil!

Comment: Si quieres mejorar tu respuesta además de conocer el sitio entonces deberías leer [ask], [answer] y pasar el [tour] si no lo has hecho. Una respuesta de calidad no solo debería mostrar código sino en lo posible señalar el error del AP, de que trata su solución, etc.